# ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException (again)

Tags: java, tomcat, soap

I had to migrate my tomcat to a new physical server. Therefore I decided to use Java11 instead of Java8, which I used previously on my tomcat machine. And of course I got troubles with the now missing packages which moved to external sources. I read the posts in here and tried to fix it, but I still get this error at calling a soap service, no matter what. Unfortunately I do not use any maven or ant or anything so I included the jars from the mavenrepo. Here's a list of the jar's I (think) I included:

- jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
- jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar
- javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar
- rt-2.3.1.jar
- streambuffer-1.5.3.jar
- policy-2.7.5.jar
- stax-ex-1.8.jar
- javax.jws-api-1.1.jar
- saaj-impl-1.5.0.jar
- gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar

I think it works, as the jar's are placed in the WEB-INF/lib folder after deployment. But still there is no way for tomcat to find that class. What am I doing wrong here? Any advice is highly appreciated, as usual ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar`.

If you look at the Maven dependencies for the jar files you have, you will see that the following two jar files depend on `jaxb-api`:

- [`jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1)
- [`jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.3.1)

Comment: Thx for the hint. I fiddeled around a bit and I think I got it running. As I had the initial 'to-add' list of jars from here, I guess it wouldn't hurt to post a complete list with the extended jaxb-api.

Answer (score 0):

All the jars I needed to get it running:

- jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
- jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar
- javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar
- rt-2.3.1.jar
- streambuffer-1.5.3.jar
- policy-2.7.5.jar
- stax-ex-1.8.jar
- javax.jws-api-1.1.jar
- saaj-impl-1.5.0.jar
- gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar
- javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
- jaxb-api.2.3.1.jar
- jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar
- jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar